# changing an image with another when button is clicked and changing jtextarea when radiobutton is selected

Tags: java, colors, jtextarea, imageicon, jradiobutton

so, i'm still a beginners in java and my project is due few days 
and i'm still stuck in those 2 problems 
i'v searched a lot and read that it should work 
but it won't 
I have an image in the frame and few buttons i want when a button is pressed the image would change.

public class animals extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

```
static JPanel buttons =new JPanel();

static JLabel intro =new JLabel("Guess what the animal that makes the noise and press to find out!");

Icon birdy=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("bird.png"));
JLabel bird=new JLabel(birdy,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon eleph=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("elephant.jpg"));
JLabel elephant=new JLabel(eleph,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon tig=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("tiger.png"));
JLabel tiger=new JLabel(tig,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon wol=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("wolf.png"));
JLabel wolf=new JLabel(wol,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon caat=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("caat.jpg"));
JLabel cat=new JLabel(caat,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon coww=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("cow.png"));
JLabel cow=new JLabel(coww,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon dogy=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("dog.png"));
JLabel dog=new JLabel(dogy,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon ducky=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("duck.jpg"));
JLabel duck=new JLabel(ducky,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon horsey=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("horse.png"));
JLabel horse=new JLabel(horsey,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon moonkey=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("monkey.png"));
JLabel monkey=new JLabel(moonkey,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon poke=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("pokemons.jpg"));
JLabel pokemon=new JLabel(poke,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon pika=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("pikachu.png"));
JLabel pikachu=new JLabel(pika,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon chari=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("charizard.png"));
JLabel charizard=new JLabel(chari,SwingConstants.CENTER);
Icon pic=new ImageIcon();
JLabel picture=new JLabel(pic,SwingConstants.CENTER);

static JButton catb=new JButton("Meow~~");
static JButton dogb=new JButton("Woof Woof~~");
static JButton horseb=new JButton("Hihi-n~~");
static JButton duckb=new JButton("Quack~~");
static JButton monkeyb=new JButton("Ki-Ki~~");
static JButton elephantb=new JButton("Pao--n~~");
static JButton cowb=new JButton("Moo~~");
static JButton birdb=new JButton("pichu pichu~~");
static JButton wolfb=new JButton("Awwooo~~");
static JButton tigerb=new JButton("Rawr~~");





public void animals()
{
    animals add =new animals();
    add.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add.setVisible(true);
    add.setTitle("Letters");
    add.setSize(500,550);
    add.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    add.add(intro);

    add.add(pokemon);

    buttons.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    buttons.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttons, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 
    buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));

    add.add(catb);
    buttons.add(horseb);
    buttons.add(duckb);
    buttons.add(elephantb);
    buttons.add(dogb);
    buttons.add(birdb);
    buttons.add(tigerb);
    buttons.add(monkeyb);
    buttons.add(wolfb);
    buttons.add(cowb);
    buttons.add(pikachu);
    buttons.add(charizard);
    add.add(picture);
    add.add(buttons);
    catb.addActionListener(add);
    horseb.addActionListener(add);
    elephantb.addActionListener(add);
    duckb.addActionListener(add);
    dogb.addActionListener(add);
    birdb.addActionListener(add);
    tigerb.addActionListener(add);
    monkeyb.addActionListener(add);
    wolfb.addActionListener(add);
    cowb.addActionListener(add);


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    if(ae.getSource()==catb)
    {
     picture.setIcon(caat);

    }
    if(ae.getSource()==horseb)
    {
        pokemon.setIcon(horsey);
    }



}
```

}

the other thing is the radiobutton 
i want when it's pressed, the text area color will change 
again read it should work, but it doesn't

```
public class colors extends JFrame implements ItemListener {

JPanel pc=new JPanel();

JRadioButton red=new JRadioButton("Red");
JRadioButton blue=new JRadioButton("Blue");
JRadioButton black=new JRadioButton("Black");
JRadioButton pink=new JRadioButton("Pink");
JRadioButton yellow=new JRadioButton("Yellow");
JRadioButton green=new JRadioButton("Green");
JRadioButton orange=new JRadioButton("Orange");

Icon meow=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("meowtwo.png"));
JLabel meowtwo=new JLabel(meow,SwingConstants.CENTER);

JLabel hi=new JLabel("explore the colors !!!");

JTextArea color=new JTextArea(20,40);

static ButtonGroup col=new ButtonGroup();



public void colors()
{
    colors add =new colors();
    add.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add.setVisible(true);
    add.setTitle("Letters");
    add.setSize(500,550);
    add.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    pc.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    hi.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,40));
    color.setEditable(false);
    col.add(red);
    col.add(blue);
    col.add(black);
    col.add(pink);
    col.add(yellow);
    col.add(green);
    col.add(orange);

    color.setBackground(color.getBackground());
    pc.add(hi);
    pc.add(meowtwo);


    add.add(pc);
    add.add(red);
    add.add(blue);
    add.add(black);
    add.add(pink);
    add.add(yellow);
    add.add(green);
    add.add(orange);
    add.add(color);

    red.addItemListener(add);
    blue.addItemListener(add);
    black.addItemListener(add);
    pink.addItemListener(add);
    yellow.addItemListener(add);
    green.addItemListener(add);
    orange.addItemListener(add);



}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
    colors add=new colors();
    if(red.isSelected())
    {
        add.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);
    }
    else
        color.setBackground(Color.yellow);
}
```

}

i know my code is not the best but again i'm still learning
please help this poor struggling student

Answer (score 0):

`animals add =new animals();` remove this line
`colors add = new colors();` and remove this line.

because you have said your classes extend `JFrame` you don't need to create any instances of your classes. instead replace `add` with the keyword this instead and everything should work.

also because your classes implement the `ActionListener` interface you can say `wolfb.addActionListener(this)` or `orange.addItemListener(this);` this will tell the compiler to look for either `itemStateChanged` or `actionPerformed` methods in that class.

when you have made those changes your code should work as expected :)

Comment: oh man !! i can't believe i forgot this ! you really saved me, thank you so much :)))))))))